# Journey Builder- There are no valid subscribers.ErrorCode: 180008

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I have a journey builder which sends a welcome email after a contact is created in salesforce. Here is the flow

Salesforce Data Event==>Send Email

But the jurney builder fails at Send Email step with below error.

> A subscriber error occurred invoking triggered send. StatusMessage:
>   Unable to queue Triggered Send request.  There are no valid
>   subscribers.ErrorCode: 180008 SubscriberFailureDescription: Error
>   Code:10 - The subscriber is missing required attribute value for First
>   Name

Tried few things but could not succeed. Can you please provide some insight?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is quite descriptive on this one

> The subscriber is missing required attribute value for First Name

It looks like this account has a Profile Attribute named First Name that is set to **required**. When email sends are made in Journey Builder it will add any new subscribers to your All Subscribers list with only the Subscriber Key and Email Address fields populated. Since it can't pass a value for the First Name Profile Attribute, it is leading to the error.

I would suggest updating the Profile Attribute itself to save this from happening again. You can either remove the Profile Attribute and then re-create it as **not required** (you can't switch this setting once the field is created unfortunately), or just set a default value on the field.

In general I wouldn't recommend having any Profile Attributes be required - it seems to just cause more pain than anything.

Comment: Thank you. That was the issue. what is the best practice then? If we don't set as required, how do we make sure we get the right data? Please suggest.

Comment: Managing Profile Attributes within SFMC is painful in general, as a lot of functionality will not by default populate it. I would suggest to effectively ignore it - you have a Sales Cloud integration, use that as your source of truth. Push all data updates into Sales Cloud, and have that flow into SFMC through Synchronized Data Extensions and your Event Data Extensions from Journey Builder.